# Insert values from FORM to DB using AJAX on october cmd

Tags: ajax, database, forms, laravel, octobercms

I'm trying to get form data and put it into the database using ajax.

I'm missing the DB insert part.

Couldn't find appropriate documentation on this one.

Please advice.

(it is a very basic usage. basic form, ajax and db)

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see here the tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_database.htm